# Simple twitter application

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

I'm trying to make a simple way to post a tweet to twitter, nothing more, nothing less. I cannot find a decent tutorial or documentation related to this... there is 10 libraries for it, can't figure out how to use none of them, don't even wan't to bother with it to be honest I JUST WANNA POST... This is what I'm aiming for, still it is not working:

```
    private void TweetBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create a webclient with the twitter account credentials,which will be used to set the HTTP header or basic authentication
        client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential { UserName = usernameTxtBox.Text, Password = password.Password } };
        // Don't wait to receive a 100 Continue HTTP response from the server before sending out the message body
        //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        // Construct the message body
        byte[] messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("status=" + messageTxtBox.Text);
        // Send the HTTP headers and message body (a.k.a. Post the data)
        client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml", UriKind.Absolute), messageTxtBox.Text);


    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well for one thing I don't see you using OAuth anywhere here so that's going to be a problem. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq

Comment: Well yes, have no clue how to use it... I've found their "user guide" which is full of fascinating facts about when it was released and revised, but nothing about the usage. Though my guess is they have hidden it somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is to share a message to Twitter, why not just use the [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)?

You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) a sample code on how to use it!

Comment: If I don't find another solution than, I'll use that. The reason why I don't want to use that is, because in ShareStatusTask there is an option to share something on your facebook wall as well, and I just want to share on twitter.

Answer (score 2):

To post on Twitter (and Facebook, in fact) you need to create an application on their website :

https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

After that you will be able to use the link and use the application (with a webbrowser for example) to identify yourself and post.

On twitter it's easy to retrieve posts because they are **public** but if you want to post it's a little bit more complicated because it's **private**.

Comment: Yes I had created an an app on their site, as the matter of fact I have a pretty neat facebook application as well which was pretty straight forward compared to this... but still I'm stuck and I don't know what to do...

Comment: I'm getting a "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." error if this means something to you

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples online for how to do such a task. Here's one: http://buildmobile.com/twitter-in-a-windows-phone-7-app/#fbid=ZBemxKxAznK

The README of [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) also includes details of authenticating and sending a tweet. If you want to use an existing library.

You should be wary of asking questions like this in the future. Your question is very broad and to answer it fully would mean explaining HTTP, OAuth, the Twitter API and good security principles around asking users for their passwords. This is beyond what StackOverflow is intended for.

See https://stackoverflow.com/faq, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and also http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Comment: how is it not working? Be specific! http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Comment: The 1st exapmle doesn't return the request token (I have followed all the instructions). Tweetsharp documentation is not in sync with the product version, and I have a lot of exceptions in the code I cannot resolve. It may even work if I pester with it a week or two, but I don't have time for that, that's why I asked for a simple solution.